How to get typescript to infer the literal string value for a type, rather than the generic `string`
I am writing a library to define schemas.
Consider the following example:
type Cardinality = 'many' | 'one';

type ValueType = 'string' | 'number';

interface ILinkDef<Source> {
  fwdCardinality: Cardinality;
  revNamespace: keyof Source;
  revCardinality: Cardinality;
  revLabel: string;
}

interface IAttrsDef {
  [label: string]: ValueType
}

interface ILinksDef<Source> {
  [label: string]: ILinkDef<Source>
}

interface ISchemaDef<Source> {
  [table: string]: {
    attrs: IAttrsDef;
    links: ILinksDef<Source>;
  };
}

class Schema<D extends ISchemaDef<any>> {
  defs: D
  constructor(
    defs: D,
  ) {
    this.defs = defs
  }
}

function schema<D extends ISchemaDef<D>>(defs: D) {
  return new Schema<D>(defs);
}

const s = schema({
  posts: {
    attrs: {
      title: 'string'
    },
    links: {
      owner: {
        fwdCardinality: 'one',
        revNamespace: 'users',
        revLabel: 'ownedPosts', 
        revCardinality: 'many'
      }      
    }
  },
  users: {
    attrs: {
      email: 'string'
    },
    links: {}
  }
})

type OwnerLink = typeof s.defs.posts.links.owner

Problem
OwnerLink returns the following inference:
type OwnerLink = {
  fwdCardinality: "one";
  revNamespace: "users";
  revLabel: string;
  revCardinality: "many";
}

I am really happy to have the literal values for fwdCardinality, revCardinality, etc.
However, I can't get revLabel to refine itself into it's literal value. I would love for revLabel to be 'ownedPosts'
Question
How could I get revLabel to keep the inference to it's literal argument, when possible?
Playground Link

the definition of ILinkDef specifies revLabel to be just string, though. Do you want to change it to a generic?

I would love to change it to be generic, but I am not sure how I would then 'fill' in that generic value with what is provided in the schema

Your original definition of ILinkDef specifies revLabel to be just string. It can be changed to a generic, though. For example:
type Cardinality = 'many' | 'one';

type ValueType = 'string' | 'number';

interface ILinkDef<Source, T extends string = string> {
  fwdCardinality: Cardinality;
  revNamespace: keyof Source;
  revCardinality: Cardinality;
  revLabel: T;
}

interface IAttrsDef {
  [label: string]: ValueType
}

interface ILinksDef<Source, T extends string = string> {
  [label: string]: ILinkDef<Source, T>
}

interface ISchemaDef<Source, T extends string = string> {
  [table: string]: {
    attrs: IAttrsDef;
    links: ILinksDef<Source, T>;
  };
}

class Schema<D extends ISchemaDef<any, any>> {
  defs: D
  constructor(
    defs: D,
  ) {
    this.defs = defs
  }
}

function schema<D extends ISchemaDef<D, T>, T extends string = string>(defs: D) {
  return new Schema<D>(defs);
}

const s = schema({
  posts: {
    attrs: {
      title: 'string'
    },
    links: {
      owner: {
        fwdCardinality: 'one',
        revNamespace: 'users',
        revLabel: 'ownedPosts', 
        revCardinality: 'many'
      }      
    }
  },
  users: {
    attrs: {
      email: 'string'
    },
    links: {}
  }
})

type OwnerLink = typeof s.defs.posts.links.owner

Playground Link

The resulting type OwnerLink is the following type: type OwnerLink = { fwdCardinality: "one"; revNamespace: "users"; revLabel: "ownedPosts"; revCardinality: "many";}
